# Problems with downloading some files through proxy with web protection filter

Tags: java, httpconnection

I am trying to download different files from my web-server via:

```
 // Simplified Code!
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("p.proxy.com",3128));
 HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
 ... //adding some default Headers (Content-Type, User-Agent,...)
 ... //adding some connection properties (setRequestMethod,...)
 BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
 ... //reading the inputstream...
```

For some files it works like expected, but for some other files i get only an html page/result, which contains following **HTML-Comment**:

> < !-- If you opened this file and can see this text, then you've probably tried 
>   to download a file using the 'save target as' option in the context menu
>   when right clicking the object.
>
> Since McAfee Web Gateway is used for virus scanning your browser is 
>   redirected to a page that will show the download
>   progress, and by chosing the 'save target as' option you were saving this 
>   progress page.
>
> To avoid this situation please use a simple click with the left mouse 
>   button to download the object. This will correctly redirect your
>   browser to display the download progress and allow you to save the
>   desired object.-->

The same bevahiour can be seen, when entering a problemtic URL into an Browser-Window.
First an (McAfee)HTML-Waiting-Page is shown, after a few seconds the Browser shows the regular Open/Save Dialog.

When I instruct my Webserver to (AES-)encrypt the requested file, before sending it, the WebProtection seems to be in-active and i can download the file as usual (without Waiting-Page).

**Question**
What can i do, to get the requested file (with Java) when the Web-Protection(-Waiting-Page) is active?

**Edit**
I can't change any (firewall) settings, the web-proxy is first scanning the file (and is showing this waiting/scanning/progress-page) and then the Browsers save/open dialog appears.

When I am trying to get the file with Java, i only get this waiting/scanning-page.

Comment: Your firewall doesn't work correctly together with java

Comment: @Ferrybig: it's a companies WebProxy which is scanning only some content.

Comment: I think you need to check the firewall settings.

Comment: @MohitSharma: i can't change any settings, i edited my question